# How to fill gaps in images in matlab / python

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I'm using image processing to try and develop a 'blob' of light. The first picture attached is the original image, and the second image is the processed image.

[image: Original image]

[image: Processed image]

My goal is to create a shape to describe the blob of light, then perform analysis on this. The next picture is where I've manually drawn an outline to describe how this could look:

[image: Blob outline]

I'm not too sure how I could 'ignore' or 'fill in' the black areas of the blob shape : (

- Sketch of areas that I'm attempting to 'fill in' so that I have a rough blob shape :
  [image: Rough sketch]

Some current basic matlab code to process the original image is below, however I've been trying solutions to inpaint on both python and matlab.

```
Shot7 = im('Shot7.TIFF');

x = double(Shot7);
xb = (2*x);


y=uint8(xb);
y=double(y);

imshow(uint8(40*(y-250)))
```

Comment: It is unclear to me  that your "developed" picture is anything useful. It appears to mostly be a threshold cut to make a binary soot and whitewash image with very noisy edges. It has lost completely the subtle rays at NW, N and NE. Is that the intention? Try histogram equalisation instead. A bit of low pass filtering first would give a more useful and less noisy image. Interpolating between the known data should be possible if  you can define which parts of the image need to be "doctored". However, it will inevitably add artefacts.  What is the image of and why do you want an outline of it?

Comment: @MartinBrown the image itself is a reflection of a proton beam, and the 'blob' in question is the excess light that's been reflected. The developed picture is all that I really need in terms of accuracy of the blob, however getting the tape removed is the biggest road block for me currently, i.e. the black lines and shape over the original image

Comment: Can you add a sketch of roughly how it will look when *"filled in"* please? Is the black bit always the same shape? Size? Orientation?

Comment: how do you go from first to second image and what meaning does this capture? you seem to be picking an arbitrary threshold that goes right through the distribution of the spotlight, instead of separating it from the darkness.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've edited the question to include a very rough (and crude) MS paint drawing to try and illustrate what I'm attempting the end result to be. The black bars and oval shape on the inside of the blob is relatively similar to each other in different captures of the experiment, however there are slight variations in each picture of the co-ordinates so I haven't attempted to manually remove them

Comment: Dilate and then erode.  You could even skip the erode part probably depending on your use case.

Comment: The simplest way might be to allow the software to automatically generate a contour for the various wanted regions and then eliminate the internal parts to make a convex hull. Then any old flood fill algorithm will zap your unwanted black bits.  You might want to try histogram stretching mapping 64 to 0 and 192 to 256 as a less brutal alternative to hard thresholding. Low pass filtering first would also help to get rid of the high frequency shot noise. Playing with it inside a proper image processing package might be more intuitive and informative.

Comment: @MartinBrown Unrelated: What do you call a proper image processing package please?

Comment: Depending on what manipulations you want the likes of Photoshop, gimp or PaintShop Pro (all of which have tools to do most of what the OP asked for). Histogram adjustment and/or equalisation can be very powerful at bringing out tiny differences in contrast (likewise false colour palettes). Various others that are specific to amateur and professional astronomy. I don't really approve of doctoring data with missing bits but if that's what the OP wants to do then doing it in a tool that has magic infill of gaps would seem to be the way to go. It is quite difficult to do well.

Answer (score 1):

I had a try using some *"TopHat"* morphology. I did it with **ImageMagick** but the same functionality is available in [wand](https://pypi.org/project/Wand/) with Python and **OpenCV**.

So, the basic idea is to get the software to *"fill in"* anywhere a given shape will fit. I'll show the results with a 47x47 rectangle as the shape we want to find first - because it allows you to better see what it is doing:

```
magick proton.png -colorspace gray -negate -threshold 50% -morphology tophat rectangle:47x47 -negate result.png
```

[image]

Now using a disk (which is actually more appropriate to match your *"tape"*) with radius 25:

```
magick proton.png -colorspace gray -negate -threshold 50% -morphology tophat disk:25 -negate result.png
```

[image]

Now with a smaller disk, radius 12:

```
magick proton.png -colorspace gray -negate -threshold 50% -morphology tophat disk:12 -negate result.png
```

[image]

You may need to draw your enclosing red line around the beam first and then flood-fill around the outside first to prevent the morphology filling that area too. Or you may want to difference the morphology-processed image with your original to find what it has filled in and then mask out the areas outside your red line.

---

Note that morphology generally looks for white objects on a black background, but you want to find the black *"tape"*, so I negated (inverted) your image, did the processing and then negated again.